# Django Group By query

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a django model as below:

```
class Recovery(models.Model):
    Branch_Code = models.IntegerField('Branch Code',max_length=5, default=None)

    RedDate = models.DateField('RecDate')

    PrincipalRec = models.DecimalField('Principal Recovery',max_digits=18,decimal_places=2,default=None)
    IntRec = models.DecimalField('Interest Recovery',max_digits=18,decimal_places=2,default=None)
    ARC_Cash = models.DecimalField('ARC Cash Recovery',max_digits=18,decimal_places=2,default=None)
    ARC_SR = models.DecimalField('ARC SR Recovery',max_digits=18,decimal_places=2,default=None)
    Total_Rec = models.DecimalField('Total Recovery',max_digits=18,decimal_places=2,default=None)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.CIF

    def Total_Rec_lacs(self):
        return round(self.Total_Rec / 100000 ,4)
    def PrincipalRec_lacs(self):
        return round(self.PrincipalRec / 100000 ,4)
    def IntRec_lacs(self):
        return round(self.IntRec / 100000 ,4)
    def ARC_Cash_lacs(self):
        return round(self.ARC_Cash / 100000 ,4)
    def ARC_SR_lacs(self):
        return round(self.ARC_SR / 100000 ,4)
```

this query does group by on "Branch_Code"

```
top5 = Recovery.objects.filter(RedDate__gte =  fromdate,RedDate__lte = todate,Total_Rec__gt=0).exclude(AssetType='AUCA').values('Branch_Code')\
            .annotate(PrincipalRec=Sum('PrincipalRec'),IntRec=Sum('IntRec'),ARC_Cash=Sum('ARC_Cash'),Total_Rec=Sum('Total_Rec')).order_by('-Total_Rec')[:5]
```

Here **fromdate** and **todate** are variables having valid date values. The above query for top5 is working fine, however I want the amount to be divide by 100 000 so that the amount will return in lacs(The above query returns whole amount).

I have tried below code, but no luck:

```
top5npa = Recovery.objects.filter(RedDate__gte =  fromdate,RedDate__lte = todate,Total_Rec__gt=0).exclude(AssetType='AUCA').values('Branch_Code')\
            .annotate(PrincipalRec=Sum('PrincipalRec')/100000,IntRec=Sum('IntRec')/100000,ARC_Cash=Sum('ARC_Cash')/100000,Total_Rec=Sum('Total_Rec')/100000).order_by('-Total_Rec')[:5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could user `F` objects to construct expressions inside Sum call

```
from django.db.models import F

...
.annotate(PrincipalRec=Sum(F('PrincipalRec')/100000), ... )
```

**ATTN**: This is not actually the same query that you asked, but `Sum(xxx)/100000` should works same as `Sum(xxx/100000)` in case of decimal fields

And here is the same query, but using undocumented parts of django

```
from django.db.models import Value

...
.annotate(PrincipalRec=Sum('PrincipalRec')/Value(100000), ... )
```